# Andoroid. Переопределить главную страницу

Tags: android, android-manifest

Как можно переопределить главную страницу, которая прописана в Manifests.

Например, у меня есть главная страница LoginForm и вот мы залогинились и перешли на страницу с новостями (NewsActivity). Я нажимаю кнопку назад и он меня возвращает обратно к LoginForm. Как сделать так, чтоб после того, как пользователь залогинется, главной страницей будет NewsActivity.

Comment: Вашей "главной страницей" должна быть NewsActivity, которая проверяет, залогинился пользователь или нет. Если нет - выводит форму регистрации\логина, если да - продолжает работать.

Comment: @pavlofff как можно реализовать в Activity данную проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете переопределить действие по кнопке "назад"

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            // Действие
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Если же вам нужно пропускать LoginForm при следующем запуске приложения, просто проверяйте, залогинен ли пользователь, если залогинен сразу открывайте из LoginForm NewsActivity.